# Making $(0,1)$ complete with a metric $d$ which defines the same topology as that of the Euclidean metric

Tags: metric-spaces

Can we define a metric $d$ on $(0,1)$ such that the topology induced by this metric is same as that of the usual Euclidean metric  on this set ?

Comment: We'll you certainly can't do it in a way that would make $(0,1)$ complete, since then $(0,1)$ would be complete with the usual metric.

Comment: @ Tim Raczkowski : Why ???!! completeness is not a topological property ....

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using the usual metric is that a sequence could be approaching $0$ or $1$, but it would not converge in $(0,1)$.  So you need to define a metric that makes $0$ or $1$ "infinitely far away" (loosely speaking) from any point in $(0,1)$, but that preserves open sets.  You can do this by finding a continuous map from $(0,1)$ onto the reals, and applying the standard metric on the mapped values.